# Why does the using statement work on IEnumerator and what does it do?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer

Back when I was learning about `foreach`, I read somewhere that this:

```
foreach (var element in enumerable)
{
    // do something with element
}
```

is basically equivalent to this:

```
using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var element = enumerator.Current;

        // do something with element
    }
}
```

Why does this code even compile if neither `IEnumerator` nor `IEnumerator<T>` implement `IDisposable`? C# language specification only seems to mention the `using` statement in the context of `IDisposable`.

What does such an `using` statement do?

Comment: `IEnumerator<T>` *does* inherit from `IDisposable`. And if you'll refer to your `enumerator` as `IEnumerator` it will not compile since it isn't `IDisposable`

Comment: @ haim770 Wow, that was a major oversight. I have no idea how I missed it. I was probably too quick to judge after seeing that `IEnumerator` doesn't. Feeling embarrassed right now.

Comment: Also note that `foreach` works with duck-typed instances. If only the compile-time type has a public non-static method `GetEnumerator()` whose compile-time return type has suitable `MoveNext()` method and `Current` property, it will work. And `IDisposable` is no _requirement_ there. A small example: `class MyFirstStrangeType
  {
    public MySecondStrangeType GetEnumerator() { return new MySecondStrangeType(); }
  }
  class MySecondStrangeType
  {
    public bool MoveNext() { return DateTime.Now.Year < 2100; }
    public DateTime Current { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
  }`

Comment: _(continued)_ You try the small example out with: `var strange = new MyFirstStrangeType();
      foreach (var x in strange)
      { Console.WriteLine(x.TimeOfDay); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, check the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx)  about **foreach** statement. It uses try/finally block with Dispose call if it's possible. That's the code which is behind **using** statement.

Comment: The documentation in your __link__ is from a very old version of the C# Language Specification (C# 1.2). A newer one can be found online, or if you use MS Visual Studio, in a folder like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx"` (version number will vary). However, for the newest versions, C# 7.0 and C# 6.0, the official spec is not ready yet.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good point. Anyway, I don't think that foreach statement was modified much.

Comment: It was changed in C# 2.0 to handle explicitly the new generic interfaces `IEnumerable<>` and `IEnumerator<>`. Your version only knows of the old non-generic ones. It was changed again in C# 5.0 to change the closure semantics when an anonymous function (such as a lambda) _captures_ or _closes over_ the loop variable. It may have changed at other occasions too. However, the rule with `Dispose` is still more or less the same: Call it if the _compile-time_ type implements or inherits `IDisposable`.

Comment: Err, I was wrong, it is called if only the _run-time_ type implements or inherits `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerator` may not implement `IDisposable` but [`GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) which does. From the docs on `IEnumerator<T>`:

> In addition, IEnumerator implements IDisposable, which requires you to implement the Dispose method. This enables you to close database connections or release file handles or similar operations when using other resources. If there are no additional resources to dispose of, provide an empty Dispose implementation.

This is of course assuming that your enumeration is an `IEnumerable<T>` and not just a `IEnumerable`. If your original enumeration was just an `IEnumerable` then it wouldn't compile.

Comment: `enumerable` could be a non-generic `IEnumerable` and that does return the non-generic `IEnumerator`.

Comment: @juharr Yes, hence the last line I added.

Comment: Then isn't this a half answer?

Comment: @juharr No, it answers why the code compiled and why it implements `IDisposable`

Comment: OK, yeah I guess I see where you're going with this now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears no one answered the main question yet:

> What does such a using statement do?

I'll go with an example from one of my favorite books - [C# in Depth](https://csharpindepth.com/) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). You may have a result of `IEnumerator<T>` produced by a function like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Iterator()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before first yield");
        yield return "first";
        Console.WriteLine("Between yields");
        yield return "second";
        Console.WriteLine("After second yield");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In finally block");
    }
}
```

And then you would use it like:

```
foreach (string value in Iterator())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received value: {0}", value);
    if (value != null)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

The iterator returns only the first `"first"` value from the sequence as we break on the very first iteration. Now how your iterator might 'know' that you aren't going to proceed till the end of the loop so it would fire it's `finally` block? Here comes the hidden `using` statement. That's how the code from the example above would look like if you couldn’t use a `foreach` loop:

```
IEnumerable<string> enumerable = Iterator();
using (IEnumerator<string> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string value = enumerator.Current;
        Console.WriteLine("Received value: {0}", value);
        if (value != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When we leave the scope of the hidden `using` statement, the `Dispose()` method fires:

```
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("In finally block");
}
```

*All of the code lines and some of the text above are provided by Jon Skeet. I could have rewritten it but decided that I should rather leave it intact. If the author doesn't want me to share it - I'll delete the answer or rewrite it ASAP.